# Why is the sum of two functions expressed as simple functions is the sum of the weighted indicator variable of the intersection?

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

If

$$g=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \mathbb I_{A_i}$$

and

$$h=\sum_{i=1}^m b_j \mathbb I_{B_j}$$

why is

$$g + h = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m (a_i + b_j) \mathbb I_{A_i\cap B_j}$$

I would have guessed that the sum would use the indicator variable $\mathbb I_{A_i \cup B_j},$ which is to say the union of both measurable sets.

Comment: Is this an intended formula for the product? Note how it looks a bit weird if $h$ and $g$ are the same thing

Comment: @leslietownes I may be missing something here, but the context of the question is getting stuck in this proof at [this particular point in this lecture](https://youtu.be/XNPPLX75hss?t=754).

Comment: In the video I see $a_i + b_j$ written as the coefficient on the last line where you've written $a_i b_j$.  That might be part of the problem.  There would potentially be double counting with a "union" formula. Also, even if you replace $a_i b_j$ with $a_i + b_j$, the sum seems to be missing terms to account for subsets that might be subsets of only some of the $A_i$ or only some of the $B_j$ but not both (e.g. it would give the sum of $0$ if the sets $A_i$ and $B_j$ are mutually pairwise disjoint, which doesn't seem right for a sum of indicators).

Comment: @leslietownes Thank you for picking up this oversight. I'll correct it now, but I agree with the last part of your last comment, which is what bothered me in the first place.

Comment: These simple functions may not be so simple after all. :) Assuming the $A_i$ are pairwise disjoint among themselves and the $B_i$ are too (often assumed when writing an initial representation of a simple function), letting $A = \bigcup A_i$ and $B = \bigcup B_j$ I think you could probably fix it with adding $\sum_i a_i \mathbb{I}_{A_i \setminus B}$ and $\sum_j b_j \mathbb{I}_{B_j \setminus A}$. But do doublecheck. This stuff is so "simple" it's easy to goof up the details.

Comment: @leslietownes On a second thought, since both $A$ and $B$ are partitions of the same sample space (implied, I guess) it is impossible to have  $\mathbb{I}_{A_i \setminus B}. $ Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, it would be implied in that case I didn't watch the video long enough to see whether that was the case.  (Sometimes people only write representations of simple functions with coefficients assumed to be nonzero, and sets not assumed to partition the whole space, which is what I was implicitly assuming above but was not stated.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $g = 3 \mathbb I_{A_1}$ and $h = 4 \mathbb I_{B_1}$.
The definition is multiplying the coefficients.  The combination has the value $12$ only in the intersection, not the union.

Comment: Please see the comments, and edit to the OP. Thanks!